# Как убрать отступ в плагине timelinr-0.9.6 Jqery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вопрос такой плагин добавляет margin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и если отключить в браузере то отображает как нужно 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

плагин стандартный timelinr-0.9.6 Jqery

Answer (score 0):

Приветствую. Насколько можно судить по исходникам данного плагина - данное поведение является фичей, которую можно обосновать.
После достижения самого последнего слайда мы наблюдаем, что его позиция так же находится в середине, что с эстетической точки зрения радует глаз.

Ну если тз уж совсем жёсткое, то можете в исходниках плагина timelinr увеличить делитель 2 у делимого widthContainer, к примеру до 6.

Было:

```
$(settings.datesDiv).width(widthDate*howManyDates).css('marginLeft',widthContainer/2-widthDate/2);
```

Стало:

```
$(settings.datesDiv).width(widthDate*howManyDates).css('marginLeft',widthContainer/6-widthDate/2);
```